# Unlink account from Google

Tags: support, linked-accounts, merge-accounts

For some reason I have created my Stack Overflow account linked from my Google account. Can I create a Stack Exchange account and connect my existing Stack Overflow account to the new one and unlink it from Google?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Click "my logins" and then "add more logins" from your profile while signed in. You can register for a Stack Exchange OpenID there and it will be added to your account. You can then remove the Google credentials.

If the association doesn't quite work, give us a shout via https://stackoverflow.com/contact and we can merge the profiles for you.

Comment: When I do this, "Stack Exchange OpenID" is not listed among the options. (I see Google, Facebook, Yahoo, LiveJournal, Blogger, AOL, or "manually enter your OpenID.")

Comment: @abeboparebop Yeah, this post is out of date. Try out the instructions here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114704 instead.